# Cannot execute Connet-AzureAD with installed AzureAD Module

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I've installed the AzureAD module in my Powershell Version 7, however I cannot execute the Connect-AzureAD Cmdlet.

Any ideas?

```
PS C:\Users\User> Get-InstalledModule

Version              Name                                Repository           Description
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------
2.0.2.135            AzureAD                             PSGallery            Azure Active Directory V2 Gene…

PS C:\Users\User> Connect-AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD: The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: Have you imported the module? `Import-Module AzureAD` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/importing-a-powershell-module?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 0):

(Legacy) 'AzureAD', 'AzureADPreview' and 'MSOnline' PowerShell modules work only in **Windows** PowerShell (i.e. Windows PowerShell **5.1 or older**)

If you want to use cross-platform PowerShell versions (such as PowerShell 7+), then you need to use modern Microsoft Graph modules such as:

- [Microsoft.Graph.Users](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Users/)
- [Microsoft.Graph.Groups](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Groups/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the module?

```
Import-Module AzureAD
```

if you are trying to do same with AzureADPreview then follow this article:
[Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment : The term 'Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73804622/get-azureadmsprivilegedroleassignment-the-term-get-azureadmsprivilegedroleass/73809196#73809196)