# Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment : The term 'Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment' is not recognized

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-role-environment

Unable to execute `Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment` in powershell its giving me an error as
*Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment : The term 'Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment' is not recognized*

I tried installing AzureADPreview module, it says the module already present, but still am getting this error.

```
Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment : The term 'Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment:String) [], CommandNotFoundExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: execute the command `Get-Module -Name *AzureAD*`, you only have to have the preview version of AzureAD Module.

Also, try `Get-Command Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment`

Share the output of both command

Answer (score 2):

> Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment : The term
> 'Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment' is not recognized as the name
> of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

This error usually occurs when you don't have **`AzureADPreview`** module installed while running that command.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId <your_tenantID>
Get-Module -Name *AzureAD*
Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId aadRoles -ResourceId <your_tenantID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

***To resolve the error, you need to install*** **`AzureADPreview`** ***module***.

If you try to install that module without removing **`AzureAD`** module, you will get **error** as below:

```
 Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview
```

**Response:**
[image]

To resolve this, close the existing session and open new **PowerShell** window by running as **Administrator**.

Make sure to uninstall **`AzureAD`** module and install  **`AzureADPreview`** module like below:

```
Uninstall-Module -Name AzureAD
Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview
Import-Module AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId <your_tenantID>
Get-Module *AzureAD*
```

**Response:**
[image]

After installing **`AzureADPreview`** module, I got the response successfully when I ran below command:

```
Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId aadRoles -ResourceId <your_tenantID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Why install `AzureADPreview` when you have [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0)?

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar because Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment is a preview feature